# Why is this upload file code not working in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a problem with the upload of files in  CakePHP 2.1.  In fact, I always have the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'.
```

for the  view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Ecole',array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Ecole.logo_ecole', array('type'=>'file','class'=>'','label'=>'')); ?>
```

When I remove `array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')` I don't have the error but the upload don't work either.

For the controller:

```
if(!empty($this->data))
{    
  debug($this->data);
  $ext  = 'jpg';

  // Save success
  if($this->Ecole->save($this->data))
  {      
    // Destination folder, new filename and destination path
    $dest_folder = IMAGES . DS . 'galleries' . DS . $this->Ecole->id;
    $new_filename = $this->Ecole->id. '.' .$ext;
    $dest_path = $dest_folder . DS . $new_filename;

    // Check if destination folder exists and create if it doesn't
    if(!is_dir($dest_folder))
    {
      mkdir($dest_folder, 0755, true);
    }

    // We move the picture and rename it with his id
    if(move_uploaded_file($this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole']['tmp_name'], $dest_path))
    {
      // Show success flash message
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Picture successfully added !', true), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
        echo  "<script>  parent.location.reload(true); parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); </script>";
    }
    // Move failed
    else
    {
      // Delete picture
      //$this->Ecole->delete($this->Ecole->id);

      // Show error flash message
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error occurred while adding picture !', true), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
    }
  }
  // Save failed
  else
  {      
    // Show error flash message
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error occurred while adding picture !', true), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to do it right?

Answer (score 2):

to do multipart/form-data, you have to specify it this way with the helper

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Ecole', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
```

The type can be `‘post’, ‘get’, ‘file’, ‘put’ or ‘delete’`. Please see the sections `Options for create` here in the [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) documentation !

Comment: thanks for your answer but even if i change array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data') by

array('type' => 'file') , i still have the same probleme??????

Comment: this is because one of your line receives an Array instead of a column name. I don<t see exactly where it is right now, but it has nothing to do with the create. It's probably one of your input

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're trying to save the array cake generates when uploading a file (`$this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole']` is an array). Are you meaning to save only the filename to the database?

Answer (score 0):

i have modify your code please take a look

and please not remove `array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')` this line in form

```
<?php

if(!empty($this->data))
{    
    debug($this->data);
    $ext  = 'jpg';


      // Destination folder, new filename and destination path
    $dest_folder = IMAGES . DS . 'galleries' . DS . $this->Ecole->id;
    $new_filename = $this->Ecole->id. '.' .$ext;
    $dest_path = $dest_folder . DS . $new_filename;

    // Check if destination folder exists and create if it doesn't
    if(!is_dir($dest_folder))
    {
      mkdir($dest_folder, 0755, true);
    }

    $image='';

    // We move the picture and rename it with his id
    if(move_uploaded_file($this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole']['tmp_name'], $dest_path))
    {
        $image = basename($this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole']['name'])

        // Show success flash message
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Picture successfully added !', true), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
        echo  "<script>  parent.location.reload(true); parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); </script>";

    }else
    {
      // Delete picture
      //$this->Ecole->delete($this->Ecole->id);

      // Show error flash message
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error occurred while adding picture !', true), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
    }   


    $this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole'] = $image;

      // Save success
      if(!$this->Ecole->save($this->data))
      {      
        // Show error flash message
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error occurred while adding picture !', true), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
      }

}
```

Comment: thank you a lot .when using your modificatons the upload works but not the insertion   the probleme now is in $this->Ecole->save($this->data) note : it don't give me any error

Comment: can i see you db table please or let me know what is you image field name in db table

Comment: id  int(11)    
 Nom_ecole  varchar(255) 
 Adresse_ecole  text  
 Tel_fix  varchar(255) 
 Tel_mobile  varchar(255)  
 Mail_ecole  varchar(255) 
 Patente_ecole  varchar(255)  
 cnss_ecole  varchar(255)  
 Slogon_ecole  text  
 logo_ecole  varchar(1000)  
 niveau_ecole_id  int(11) 
 user_id  int(255)    
 dt_sup  datetime   
 dt_modif  datetime                                       this is my bd table and the image field name is logo_ecole

Comment: tell me one thing you can store only image or with full path like abc.jpg or uploads/abc.jpg

Comment: use
 
  $image = $this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole']['name'];
   
or 
   
  $image = "YOUR_PATH/".$this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole']['name'];
  
inseted of 
  
$image = basename($this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole']['name'])

Comment: it gives the error :                                                           Indirect modification of overloaded property EcolesController::$data has no effect [APP\Controller\EcolesController.php, line 65]             for the line  $this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole'] = $image

Comment: i used $image = $this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole']['name']; but i still have the robleme sory

Comment: before save set  pr($this->data); die; this code and execute your code see the output you get array and send it to me

Comment: this is what the output i have , it gives me two array array('Ecole' => array('Adresse_ecole' => '''logo_ecole' => array(
   'name' => '539245_10150637851437304_298015427303_9371329_1080160669_n.jpg',
   'type' => 'image/jpeg',
   'tmp_name' => 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpED48.tmp','error' => (int) 0,'size' => (int) 17477)))
Array([Ecole] => Array([Nom_ecole] => 
        [Mail_ecole] => 
            [Tel_fix] => 
            [Tel_mobile] => 
            [Slogon_ecole] => 
            [niveau_ecole_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 0
            [logo_ecole] => Array
                (
          
   ))

Comment: can you provide you html code because some problem in your first array array('Ecole' => array('Adresse_ecole' => '''logo_ecole' => array( 'name' => '539245_10150637851437304_298015427303_9371329_1080160669_n.jpg', 'type' => 'image/jpeg', 'tmp_name' => 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpED48.tmp','error' => (int) 0,'size' => (int) 17477)))

Comment: after 'Adresse_ecole' => '' element comma is missing

Comment: they dont give me the possibilite to write a lot of words here that why i didn't copy all the code

Comment: i think some problem in your html resolved first and make your first array correctly after then i can slove your problem

Comment: this is the first array there is no probleme with it            array(
 'Ecole' => array(
  'Nom_ecole' => '',
  'Mail_ecole' => '',
  'Patente_ecole' => '',
  'cnss_ecole' => '',
  'Adresse_ecole' => '',
  'Tel_fix' => '',
  'Tel_mobile' => '',
  'Slogon_ecole' => '',
  'niveau_ecole_id' => '1',
  'user_id' => '0',
  'logo_ecole' => array(
   'name' => 'bb.jpg',
   'type' => 'image/jpeg',
   'tmp_name' => 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpE406.tmp',
   'error' => (int) 0,
   'size' => (int) 14654
  )

Comment: this is the second array :Array
(
    [Ecole] => Array
        (
            [Nom_ecole] => 
            [Mail_ecole] => 
            [Patente_ecole] => 
            [cnss_ecole] => 
            [Adresse_ecole] => 
            [Tel_fix] => 
            [Tel_mobile] => 
            [Slogon_ecole] => 
            [niveau_ecole_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 0
            [logo_ecole] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 5.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] =>C:\wamp\tmp\phpE40.tmp [error] => 0
                    [size] => 17477
                )

        )

)

Comment: please echo this value $this->data['Ecole']['logo_ecole'] = $image; die; before this code if(!$this->Ecole->save($this->data))

Comment: finaly it works .thanks you a lot i know i make you mad thank you so mutch. this is how i resolved the probleme : $this->Ecole->set(array(
    'Nom_ecole' => $this->data['Ecole']['Nom_ecole'],
 'Adresse_ecole' =>$this->data['Ecole']['Adresse_ecole'],
 'logo_ecole' => $image
));
 $this->Ecole->save();

Comment: one more thing you have follow cakephp rule your file upload code it is core php you can use file upload components and helper it is better pratice for you